# Reset button not resetting the value to 0

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Doing a basic DOM manipulation here. Everything is working fine: when any player reaches a predefined number like 5, for now the score turns green and it stops further increment. Then, when I click the “Reset” button, it resets to “0 to 0”, but when I click any of the “Player” buttons, it continues with the previous value instead of starting from 0.

```js
/*global prompt,alert,console*/
/*jslint plusplus: true */
var button1 = document.querySelector(".button1");
var button2 = document.querySelector(".button2");
var p1Display = document.querySelector(".p1display");
var p2Display = document.querySelector(".p2display");
var reset = document.querySelector(".reset");
var val1 = 0;
var val2 = 0;
var maxVal = 5;
var gameOver = false;
button1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    'use strict';
    if (gameOver === false) {
        val1++;
        if (val1 === maxVal) {
            p1Display.classList.add("win");
            gameOver = true;
        }
        p1Display.textContent = val1;
    }
});
button2.addEventListener('click', function () {
    'use strict';
    if (gameOver === false) {
        val2++;
        if (val2 === maxVal) {
            p2Display.classList.add("win");
            gameOver = true;
        }
        p2Display.textContent = val2;
    }
});
reset.addEventListener('click', function () {
    'use strict';
    var val1 = 0;
    var val2 = 0;
    p1Display.textContent = 0;
    p2Display.textContent = 0;
    p1Display.classList.remove("win");
    p2Display.classList.remove("win");
    gameOver = false;
});
```

```css
.win{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Score Keeper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <h1><span class="p1display">0</span> to <span class="p2display">0</span></h1>
   <h3>Playing To : <span class="maxval">5</span></h3>
   <input type="number" class="setVal" min="1">
   <button class="button1">Player One</button>
   <button class="button2">Player Two</button>
   <button class="reset">Reset</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[JS Fiddle Working Link](https://jsfiddle.net/cannelflow/aghoyxLe/)

Comment: What's with the horrible capitalisation on every word in the question? Please [edit] your post and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t use `var` when resetting: in the resetting function, replace

```
var val1 = 0;
var val2 = 0;
```

by

```
val1 = 0;
val2 = 0;
```

`val1` and `val2` are already declared in an outside scope, redeclaring them in a narrower scope just creates different variables with the same name (“shadowing”): the two variables `val1` and `val2` inside the resetting function are not the same as the ones outside the function. In fact they are never used, which is why JSLint reports a redeclaration and JSHint says they are unused variables.